# Get IP address from hosts in a Group

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a simple playbook referencing an inventory hosts.yml file.  I want to be able to query a group, and retrieve the IP address for hosts in that group.

**Simple hosts.yml**

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    w2k16-std:
      ansible_host: 10.1.1.12
      in_play_ip: 10.200.2.12
    w2k12-x64:
      ansible_host: 10.1.1.13
      in_play_ip: 10.200.2.13
    lin-test:
      ansible_host: 10.1.1.20
      in_play_ip: 10.200.2.20
  children:
    windows:
      vars:
        ansible_connection: winrm
        ansible_winrm_transport: certificate
        ansible_winrm_cert_pem: /home/user/.ssh/windows.pem
        ansible_winrm_cert_key_pem: /home/user/.ssh/windows_key.pem
        ansible_port: 5986
        ansible_winrm_scheme: https
        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
      hosts:
        w2k12-x64:
        w2k16-std:
    linux:
      hosts:
        lin-test:
    targets:
      hosts:
        w2k12-x64:
        w2k16-std:
```

**Here's the simple playbook:**

```yaml
---
- hosts: kali
  vars:
  tasks:
    - name: Create comma delimited list of target names from targets group.
      set_fact:
        targets: "{{ groups.targets | list | join(',') }}"

    - name: List targets from Inventory
      debug:
        var: targets
```

Produces the following output:

```
TASK [List targets from Inventory] ***************************************
ok: [lin-test] => {
    "targets": "w2k12-x64,w2k16-std"
```

I want be able do the following:

- Retrieve the members of the `targets` group (`w2k12-x64` & `w2k16-std`)
- Get the IP address listed in `ansible_host` values.
- Create a comma delimited list of the target's IPs (`10.1.1.12,10.1.1.13`).

So far I can:

- Retrieve the members of the `targets` group (`w2k12-x64` & `w2k16-std`)
- Create a comma delimited list of the target names.

I'm not sure if my hosts file is correctly laid out, or if I just need help with the query?

**Desired output:**

Produce the following output:

```
TASK [List target IPs from Inventory] ***************************************
ok: [lin-test] => {
    "targets": "10.1.1.12,10.1.1.13"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value you are looking for from the [`hostvars` special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables).

You can also filter the items of the dictionary `hostvars` contained in the group `targets` thanks to the filters [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists), which will create a `key/value` list from the dictionary, and [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) to get only the items of the created list having a key matching in the `targets` group.

Then, you just need to reduce the list of dictionaries to a simple list via [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map), because you are only interested in the `ansible_host` attribute, and [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) the whole thing together.

So, this end up with this single task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        hostvars 
          | dict2items 
          | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.targets)
          | map(attribute="value.ansible_host")
          | join(',')
      }}
```

Which yields your expected:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 10.1.1.12,10.1.1.13
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I was looking for thank you!!

Comment: Do you have some online tutorials which we can follow to learn this with real life examples. It's a nice skill to have.

Comment: @KevinC what would you expect from that kind of tutorial that you don't already know? Here, you just have to know two "basic" things: where Ansible is storing the data (answer in `hostvars`, and honestly a through read of the _special variable_ page is always worthy) and then, what are the available filters (answer Jinja page and the extra filter in Ansible documentation).

Comment: For example, in this answer, my first intend was to provide a `loop`, then I remembered about _"dict to list should call for `dict2items`"_, so I ended up with that answer.

Comment: Pages I was referring in the previous comment: [_special variables_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html); [Jinja filters documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#builtin-filters) & [Ansible extra Jinja filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Comment: Also, read the questions and answers here. The [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ansible/topusers) for the tag [tag:ansible] is something you might refer to. The users I tend to read the answers because I feel they come with clever solution and from which I personally like the style: [Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/vladimir-botka); [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks); [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator); [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel), in no particular order.